# Ajustar o tamanho da popup window

Tags: android

Como ajustar o tamanho da popup window ao conteúdo do layout?

Tentei, sem sucesso, o seguinte:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) m_activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_info_window, null, false);

view.requestLayout();

PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(view,view.getWidth(),view.getHeight(),true);
```

main_info_window.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:padding="20dp"
              android:background="#CCCCCCCC">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Info window"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Na criação do objeto PopupWindow altere para:

```
PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,true);
```

** não é preciso chamar o método *view.requestLayout();*